# Negate the ^(```) and repeat its element

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Suppose such a markdown file

````
In [86]: !cat formatCase.md                                                                                       

Some content in the head

```
>>> '{:20,.2f}'.format(18446744073709551616.0)
'18,446,744,073,709,551,616.00'
```

When formatting an integer, include the comma after the width:

```
>>> '{:20,d}'.format(18446744073709551616)
'18,446,744,073,709,551,616'
```

some content on the foot.
````

I'd like to add language type to ```

````
In [88]: c = open("new_format.md").read()

new_c = re.sub(r"```([^`]+)```", r"```python\1```",c)
````

This solution works,
One more step, if there exist situation to make typo error inside ```, one ` or two `` occurs,

then, should replace [^`] with ^(```).

tried alternatively

````
r"```(^(```))+```"
r"```(?:^(?:```))+```"
r"```((?:^(?:```))+)```"
````

It does not perform correctly.

How could get it done to consider ^(```) situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

````
r'```([^`]*(?:``?(?!`)[^`]*)*)```'
````

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/B2BIDw/1)

**Details**

- ```` ``` ```` - 3 backticks
- ``` ([^`]*(?:``?(?!`)[^`]*)*) ``` - Group 1:

  - `` [^`]* `` - 0+ chars other than backtick
  - ``` (?:``?(?!`)[^`]*)* ``` - zero or more repetitions of

    - ``` ``?(?!`) ``` - 1 or 2 backticks not followed with another backtick
    - `` [^`]* `` - 0+ chars other than backtick
- ```` ``` ```` - 3 backticks